# Linker error for recursive calls to variadic function

Tags: c++, linker-errors, variadic-functions

I've read [Linker error for variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067433/linker-error-for-variadic-template) carefully but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

I have 3 files, `detail.h`, `detail.cpp`, and `main.cpp`.

In `detail.h` there's only one line declaring a variadic function `allSame`.

```
//detail.h
bool allSame(unsigned long...);
```

In `detail.cpp`, the implementation of the function is provided.

```
//detail.cpp
#include "detail.h"
bool allSame() { return true; }
bool allSame(unsigned long first) { return true; }
bool allSame(unsigned long first, unsigned long second) { 
    return first == second; 
}
bool allSame(unsigned long first, unsigned long second, unsigned long others...) {
    if (first == second)
        return allSame(first, others);
    else 
        return false;
}
```

As one can easily infer, the function `allSame` serves the purpose to return if its variadic arguments are all the same.

```
//main.cpp
#include "detail.h"
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    if (allSame(2, 2, 2, 2)) 
        std::cout << "All same. " << std::endl;
}
```

In compiling and linking of the above three files (using command `g++ detail.cpp main.cpp`), I received this linker error

```
/disk1/tmp/ccTrBHWU.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `allSame(unsigned long, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Indeed I didn't provide an overload with the particular signature `allSame(unsigned long, ...)`; however I did provide the function definition with 0, 1, 2, 2+(any) arguments. Perhaps the way the compiler expands the parameter pack upon function call is more delicate than I thought?

**[side note]** If I move the content of `detail.cpp` to `detail.h` then the program compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: What should it be? Variadic? Can't see templates here? Or you really want to use varargs?

Comment: This isn't the way that C-style varargs functions work. The error message is correct. I'm not going to explain it; it's complicated and nasty. Use a template.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a vararg function but you define non-vararg overloads. The compiler emits code targeting the vararg form (as that is the visible declaration) but then the linker fails to find a matching definition.

Either write declarations for the non-vararg forms or write (define) an actual vararg function, or better yet write a variadic template (the definition of which should be placed in the header file).

Answer (score 1):

In c++ we simply can write:

```
template < typename S, typename ... T>
constexpr bool allSame( S first, T ... t ) 
{   
    return ((first == t) && ...) ;
}   

int main()
{   
    std::cout << allSame( 5,4,3 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << allSame( 10,10,10,10 ) << std::endl;
}
```

So there is no need anymore to use variadic functions with varargs or use recursive templates.

But if you like recursive templates, you can take this:

```
template < typename S, typename ... T>  
constexpr bool allSame( S , T ... );

template <typename FIRST>
constexpr bool allSame( FIRST first ) { return true; }

template < typename FIRST, typename SECOND, typename ... REST>
constexpr bool allSame( FIRST first, SECOND second, REST ... rest )
{   
    if ( first != second ) return false;
    return allSame( second , rest... );
}   

int main()
{   
    std::cout << allSame( 5,4,3 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << allSame( 10,10,10,10 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Functions using the old c-style varargs should not be used. I have no idea what you want to see, because you don't use template either varargs in your code!

Comment: Note that `allSame( "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test" )` might return `true` or `false`, we do pointer comparison, and those pointers might be different.

Comment: Ubs! Thanks for the finding!